# Python: check if date is correct

Tags: python

PYTHON

Hi, the check_date code returns False - what is wrong with the coding? The first function checks how many days are in the month entered, and the second function checks if the date is in correct format.

```
'''
def days_in_month(month):
if month == 1 or month == 3 or month == 5 or month == 7 or month == 8 or month == 10 or month == 12:
return month == 31
    else:
        return 30
'''


'''

    def check_date(date):
    day = int(date[0:2])
    month = int(date[2:4])
    year = date[4:6]
    
    if ( (day<=days_in_month(month)) and (0<month<13) ):
        return True
    else:
        return False
'''    
    
print(check_date('011297'))
```

Comment: `day` is a string. try converting it to integer before comparing to `days_in_month(month)` (same applies to `month` ofc)

Comment: (Also, for `days_in_month`, you kinda forgot about February..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is on Line 3:

```
def days_in_month(month):
    if month == 1 or month == 3 or month == 5 or month == 7 or month == 8 or month == 10 or month == 12:
        return 31
    else: return 30

def check_date(date):
    day = int(date[0:2])
    month = int(date[2:4])
    year = date[4:6]

    if ( (day<=days_in_month(month)) and (0<month<13) ):
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(check_date('011297'))
```